# Toolbar home button not working if there is no option menu

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat

When using the new `Toolbar` with the appcompat support library, it seems to me that the Home button doesn't work as it used to be unless you set a valid options menu. A simple and bog standard activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.some_page);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.some_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed() or finish() or whatever();
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

If there is a menu set in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, `onOptionsItemSelected()` will be called all right with `android.R.id.home` and all is fine. However, if there is no `onCreateOptionsMenu()` at all (or it's empty, either returning `true`or calling the `super` function), `onOptionsItemSelected()` won't be called at all, thus there is no chance to catch the click on the Home button. I even tried to pass an empty menu to `onCreateOptionsMenu()` but it didn't help.

Is there a workaround that allows us to have a working Home button on pages that don't need a functional options menu?

Comment: I found this now, it slipped my attention at first because I'm *not* on JB but KK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859841/homeasup-button-has-no-effect-in-android-4-2-2-with-appcompat-21-0-0?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

You can try this..

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent =new Intent(Context,<Destination activity);
startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Hope it will help you..